# AS3: Use one button to go through multiple pages

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I want a IntroMovie for a game based of Backgrounds on different frames.

So I want to control them with 3 buttons: startBtn, backBtn and nextBtn.
You start the Movie by pressing the startBtn. The backBtn to go directly back to the startmenu and the NextBtn to go to the next image.

I want to code that if the startBtn is pressed the first image (frame 2) appears.
When you press the nextBtn I checks if its on the first image (frame 2). And if so its goes to the second image(frame 3). When you press the nextBtn again it checks if its on image 2 (frame 3). And if so its goes to the third image (frame 4) and go on.

```
//EventHandlers
//PlayBtn
function startBtnOver(e: MouseEvent) {
    startBtn.gotoAndStop(2);}
function startBtnOut(e: MouseEvent) {
    startBtn.gotoAndStop(1);}
function startBtnDown(e: MouseEvent) {
    startBtn.gotoAndStop(3);
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
    introMovie.gotoAndStop(2);
    backBtn.gotoAndStop(1);}

//BackBtn
function backBtnOver(e: MouseEvent) {
    backBtn.gotoAndStop(2);}
function backBtnOut(e: MouseEvent) {
    backBtn.gotoAndStop(1);}
function backBtnDown(e: MouseEvent) {
    startBtn.gotoAndStop(1);
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(3);}

//NextBtn
function nextBtnOver(e:MouseEvent) {
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(2);}
function nextBtnOut(e:MouseEvent) {
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(1);}
function nextBtnDown(e:MouseEvent) {
    nextBtn.gotoAndStop(3);
    introMovie.gotoAndStop(+1);}

if (introMovie == 3) {
    introMovie.gotoAndStop(4);
} else if (introMovie == 4) {
    introMovie.gotoAndStop(5);
} else {
    introMovie.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Comment: That seems to be more complicated then it needs to be I think. Should look up the MoiveClip.nextFrame() method

Comment: You have many problems with your code (you can't compare `MovieClip` with `Number`, introMovie.currentFrame == 3 this will work; You can't `.gotoAndStop(+1)`, but you can: `introMovie.nextFrame()`), and very specific task you have

Comment: Also design your buttons as SimpleButton, so you don't need custom Over/Out events

Comment: @Nicolas Silver: Thank you. It all worked what you said

Comment: You can close the question if you've got the right answer, so it won't stay opened and unanswered :)